# When updating an existing subscription, billing_cycle_anchor must be either unset, 'now', or 'unchanged' stripe billing_cycle_anchor

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to update subscription by upgrade/downgrade plan. I want to start new plan only after completing current plan's period end. Ie, now iam in 1 month plan. When I update 6months plan then should get total of 7 months of service. But amount should be deducted immediately after updating subscription.
I sent below request to stripe.subscriptions.update.
But I am getting "**When updating an existing subscription, billing_cycle_anchor must be either unset, 'now', or 'unchanged'**"

```
{ cancel_at_period_end: false,
  items: [ { id: 'si_DK9Ypv68LYxOyt', plan: 'plan_DD1O7QiWqDtfA7' } ],
  billing_cycle_anchor: 1535613276,
  prorate: false }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this with just a single plan update. When you update a subscription to a new plan it will switch immediately to it. Hopefully there is a workaround you can use to achieve this result.

You can create a one-off charge for the next period and if it succeeds update the subscription to the new plan with a trial period ending at the end of the next period. The downside is that if you update the subscription mid period Stripe won't be able to calculate the proration for you.